# How can I mount an ISO via PowerShell/programmatically?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, mount, powershell, iso-image

How can I mount and dismount ISO images from PowerShell in Windows 8 without 3rd party programs?

*This [question's](https://superuser.com/q/499026/146694) original [revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/499026/1) got me wondering if it's possible to mount an ISO via PowerShell in Windows 8.*

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/968495/how-can-an-iso-image-be-mounted-to-a-specified-drive-letter-in-powershell

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Mount an ISO from command prompt (Windows 8/2012 and above only)

If you're sitting at a command prompt and need to mount an ISO, run the following command:

> `PowerShell Mount-DiskImage`

This will invoke a PowerShell cmdlet. You will be prompted for the path of the ISOs you wish to mount. When you are done, leave the last one blank and push <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: running Mount-DiskImage cmdlet]

Tada! It's mounted:

[image: Tada! It’s mounted — “Devices with Removable Storage”]

## Dismount an ISO

To dismount an ISO from PowerShell run `Dismount-DiskImage` and follow the prompt. If you know only the drive letter off the top of your head, and not the image path, use this command:

> `Get-Volume [Drive Letter] | Get-DiskImage | Dismount-DiskImage`

This command will grab the drive you specify, find the disk image, and dismount it.

[image: “Devices with Removable Storage” after dismounting ISO]

## Mounting multiple ISOs and displaying drive letters

You can also use the `-PassThru` flag to store data passed to the command. Let’s mount a few ISOs, display their drive letters, execute a file on one of the drives, and then dismount all the ISOs.

Mount the ISOs

```
 $MountedISOs=Mount-DiskImage -PassThru D:\Downloads\Ubuntu.iso,D:\Downloads\Windows8.iso,D:\Downloads\Server2012.iso
```

Display volume info for each ISO mounted using a `foreach` loop

```
 foreach($iso in $MountedISOs){Get-Volume -DiskImage $iso}
```

List J drive

```
 ls J:\
```

Open a file

```
 start wubi.exe
```

[image: output of foreach/Get-Volume and ls]

To dismount the ISOs, use the following command:

```
 Dismount-DiskImage $MountedISOs.ImagePath
```

## Testing the ISO

To build a simple script that checks if the ISO is attached and is in fact an ISO (vs. a VHD) I like to use `-PassThru` to store the object temporarily, and use the `Get-DiskImage` command to update the status of the DiskImage object. This will update the `Attached` property. The `StorageType` property will tell you whether the file is an ISO or VHD according to its file extension.

[image: using <code>-PassThru</code> and <code>Get-DiskImage</code>]

The `StorageType` of a VHD is 2, where an ISO will return 1.
Here's the output of `$UbuntuISO`:
[image: Here's the output of <code>$UbuntuISO</code>]

This is the output of `$temp` after mounting a VHD: (`Mount-DiskImage` can also mount VHDs!)
[image: the output of <code>$temp</code> after mounting a VHD]

Note that the `Attached` property above is `False`,
despite the `Mount-DiskImage` command running without a hitch.

Keep in mind that the `$UbuntuISO` variable will not stay updated either:
[image: the <code>$UbuntuISO</code> variable does not stay updated]

---

*[Technet: Mount-DiskImage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848706.aspx)*

*[Technet: Dismount-DiskImage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848693.aspx)*

Comment: Damn, with all those new cmdlets in PowerShell Windows 8 starts to tickle.

Comment: We can easily mount the image through the command `C:\>explorer.exe imagepath`, here we don't need of PS but for unmount there we have need the PS.

Comment: Is all inside Windows 8? I mean don't you need to install other programs???

Comment: @SEARAS Yes, the Mount-DiskImage cmdlet was modified to use ISO files in Windows 8 and Server 2012. There's no need for 3rd party programs. A long overdue Windows feature in my opinion...

Comment: +1 *Very* nice indeed! This was *precisely* what I was hoping to find in Win8 so I could eventually add it to the end of my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/499176/138343), but you saved me the trouble. I really need to start boning up on my PS skills. :) Edit: Is there any cmdlet to test the innards and report whether the file is an ISO or VHD or something else entirely that's not supported? Or maybe a way to test the return value of **Mount-DiskImage** perhaps so code can be branched accordingly?

Comment: @Karan Finally got around to figuring that out =D It's not going to test the guts, and frankly I think that's overkill. But it will let us know if it's mounted and an ISO vs VHD without diving in to PowerShell error handling.

Comment: That is an exemplary answer!

Comment: See [here](https://superuser.com/a/1306633) for mounting an iso as a directory (instead of drive letter).

Answer (score 4):

Normally, if you want to do this via the command line, you need a non-interactive method. You will want to use the `-ImagePath` switch to do this.

Thus, the correct command is:

```
PowerShell Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\AbsolutePathTo\Image.iso"
```

Remember that if you quote the absolute path (for containing spaces and other special characters), you need to escape the quotes.

To dismount an iso image, remember to quote it:

```
PowerShell "Get-Volume G | Get-DiskImage | Dismount-DiskImage"
```

Note that we did not have to quote the command in the first case, but we do in the second, because the `|` pipe will cause the command line to think that it is in the command line context, rather than addition arguments to `PowerShell` (which PowerShell automatically concatenates into a single command).

Also make sure to spell `Dismount-DiskImage` correctly (no `k` in Dismount).

Comment: What does the -Command switch do, and why run non-interactive?

Comment: oops, didn't need -Command, it appears to do that automatically, non-interactive because chances are, a script is doing it rather than a human (who can just use the GUI)

Comment: Don't forget the simpler dismount by filename as well: `PowerShell Dismount-DiskImage \"C:\AbsolutePathTo\Image.iso\"`

Comment: For current dir mounts: `PowerShell Mount-DiskImage \"%CD%\Image.iso\"`