# Batch file that runs cmd.exe, several commands one after the other

Tags: windows, command-line

I'd like to make a batch file that:

1. Opens the Command Prompt
2. Mounts an .ISO
3. Then runs:

   ```
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:F:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
   SFC /SCANNOW
   ```

How would I go about doing that? I already know how to create a .bat file and how to run it as admin. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: mounting an ISO try this: powershell.exe "Mount-DiskImage ""%WindowsISO%"""

Comment: So your problem isn't actually running commands after another, but to mount an ISO?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options how to mount ISO using script: to use powershell [Mount-DiskImage](https://superuser.com/questions/499264/how-can-i-mount-an-iso-via-powershell-programmatically) commandlet (follow the link to see the ready how-to answer) or to use an external utility [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/mount-iso-file-from-command-line.htm) in a batch file.
Due to your question was about batch file here is an example with PowerISO:

```
piso mount d:\test.iso F:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:F:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
SFC /SCANNOW
```

You don't need an extra command to open command prompt - when running batch file it will start command prompt by itself.
In this example you mount file test.iso located on D: drive to a virtual drive F:

You will also need to specify the real path to piso.exe in the batch file.

Comment: So would this be correct? [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/IYWqnWB.png). And to make sure I got this right: They would run one after the other (once the previous has finished) or will they all 'try' to run at the same time?

Comment: No, you can't use PowerShell commands inside the batch script. You either do it completely as PowerShell script from scratch or as batch.

Comment: all the commands here can run as-is on powershell without problem, so just open powershell and paste them, or save as a \*.ps1 file then run. Of course if for some reason cmd is required then you can run powershell from cmd