# What is windows way to do `mount -o loop,rw,offset=X`?

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, filesystems, mount

I want to mount with `-o loopoffset=70254080` an  `./raspbian-jessie-lite.img`  onto `./mntpt` folder. The `rw` parameter is the key here - I need to edit [`.iso`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55971/36605) insides (set wifi login\password) and save it back. How to mount with rw on Windows 10?

---

Bash on Windows gives to me no loop back devices found error, while recomended

```
panda@host:~$ sudo /sbin/modprobe loop.o
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.4.0+/modules.dep.bin'
```

so I wonder, what is free or opensource or shareware software that allows to do such loopback mount thing on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

The below powershell script will take an .iso and mount it to a directory.  I assume it will work for .img, too, but am unsure if it will accept writing.

For example, `$img_path` of `D:\my_stuff\mount_me.iso`, will create a mount point at `D:\my_stuff\mount_me\`

*Note that the command* `$drive.AddMountPoint` *requires admin privileges.*

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $img_path)

##
# https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d2faa6c3-35e8-4bad-8ac8-24902bbb6f1a/what-is-the-point-of-nodriveletter-in-mountdiskimage
##

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$mount_dir_path = Join-Path `
    ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($img_path)) `
    ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($img_path))

if(-Not (Test-Path -Path $mount_dir_path -PathType "Container")) {
    $null = mkdir $mount_dir_path
}

$img = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $img_path -NoDriveLetter -PassThru
$vol = Get-Volume -DiskImage $img
$drive = Get-WmiObject "win32_volume" -Filter "Label = '$($vol.FileSystemLabel)'"
$mount_return = $drive.AddMountPoint($mount_dir_path)

if($mount_return.ReturnValue -ne 0) {
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384762(v=vs.85).aspx
    throw $mount_return
}

##
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a windows-10 expert, but I presume that being able to use bash doesn't implies that you can use the whole GNU/linux toolchain.

No loop device on windows, as far as I know
Also, no modprobe ( this is a specific of linux kernel ), and no mount probably ( this time, a specific of some file systems )

Comment: I'm guessing the OP used the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to run `bash`. WSL runs real, unmodified Linux EFI binaries, but it does not run them on a real Linux kernel but rather on a Linux-to-NT compatibility layer (in fact, it's basically the opposite of `wine`, which runs real Win32 binaries on a Win32-to-Linux compatibility layer). WSL does not support loading kernel modules, including drivers.