# Mount ISO image silent on Windows 7 without third-party software installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, mount, iso-image

I want to mount an ISO image silent to a specific drive letter on Windows 7, without installing third-party software. 
I tried with [WinCDEmu Portable](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/portable/) but it needs to be started with gui once to install the driver. Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. It is possible with [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html). 
After installed on a machine once, it's sufficient to copy OSFMount.com and OSFMount.sys from install dir to make it portable.

My batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off
set disk1=\\path\to\my\disk1.iso
set disk2=\\path\to\my\disk2.iso
set drive1=M:
set drive2=N:
.\OSFMount.com -a -t file -f %disk1% -m %drive1% 
.\OSFMount.com -a -t file -f %disk2% -m %drive2% 

%drive1%\setup.exe -silent -media_dir2 %drive2%

.\OSFMount.com -d -m %drive1%
.\OSFMount.com -d -m %drive2%
exit 0
```

Comment: I've added the WINCDEMU version aswell.

use "set VAR=%~dp0" to find current BAT file location so u can do a "portable" variant of your script

Comment: I will upvote yours, please upvote mine, and select which answer u see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with WINCDEMU portable, save the below script as .CMD file or .BAT, and place it in your USB flash drive (because it is portable so I thought).

```
    @echo off
    sleep 5
    set iso1="PATH-TO-ISO"
    set iso2="PATH-TO-ISO"
    set emupath=%~dp0
cd %emupath%
    echo "Mounting ISO = %iso1%"
    batchmnt %iso1%
        echo "Mounted !!"
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
    batchmnt %iso2%
pause
```

--- Win8 +

### This is doable through : PowerShell Mount-DiskImage

```
$mountResult = Mount-DiskImage C:\myISO.iso -PassThru
$volumeiso = $mountResult | Get-Volume
```

Then you can start a explorer window

```
ii $volumeiso:\
```

Please see :
[How can I mount an ISO via PowerShell/programmatically?](https://superuser.com/questions/499264/how-can-i-mount-an-iso-via-powershell-programmatically)

And this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-powershell

If you want a concrete script/solution please specify what you wish to happen.

Comment: This works from Windows 8 but not in Windows 7. 

See here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848706(v=wps.630).aspx

I want to create a script which automatically mounts two ISO files, starts an installation and unmounts the ISOs after that.

Comment: I am updating the answer sorry i missed that ur on WIN7

Comment: With portable I meant 'no installation required', I want to rollout this script in my network so I don't want to install third-party software only for another software installation. 

When you download WinCDEmu Portable you don't have batchmnt, you only have PortableWinCDEmu-4.0.exe.