# Windows 10: how to select multiple disks (in order to to eject them all at once)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-interface, selection, usability

Suppose:

[image]

How to select multiple disks (in order to to eject them all at once)?

If not possible, then is it a defect? Is there a need to report it to Microsoft?

Comment: "If not possible, then is it a defect?" - It is not a defect.  It's an intentional design.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer allows to select more than one disk, but the Eject
option is then not shown in the context-menu.
This is most likely by design and there is no point in reporting it to
Microsoft, except as a feature request.

If your wish to eject all DVD drives in one go, see the post
[How to eject multiple devices simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/591040/how-to-eject-multiple-devices-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Eject needs to close the attached disk so that any writing to the disk or back to the host is completed and the attached disk connection is closed. Then you can eject it.

I cannot see any way to close all files and connections simultaneously and I am quite sure this is not a bug that needs to be reported to Microsoft.

For safety, I would only eject one at a time.

Is closing 2 connections one after the other a large problem?

I would just close one and eject and then the next and eject.