# How can I automatically mount an iso image before launching a specific program on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, mount, iso-image

I have a program that needs a locally stored iso image to be mounted as virtual CD drive to work.

Currently I have both a link to the iso and a link to the application executable on the desktop. I double-click the iso which mounts it and opens an Explorer window. I close the Explorer and double-click the application.

How can I make this easier, i.e. automatically mount the iso (without opening an Explorer window) and launch the application with a single double-click?

Comment: This may help http://superuser.com/questions/480957/mount-an-iso-from-the-command-line-and-get-its-drive-letter-in-windows-8 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662684/mount-iso-file-win-windows-8-with-a-batch-file ... Then after the mount load the program (still part of the .bat file)

Comment: This might help as well: http://superuser.com/questions/499264/how-can-i-mount-an-iso-via-powershell-programmatically?rq=1